# visual studio 2010 error al encontra include

Tags: visual-studio-2010, compilacion

estoy modificando un juego pero si utilizo #include "EncryptionUtils.h" dentro del alchivo nunca lo encuentra a menos que lo agregue a proyecto [image: como se muestra en la imagen es la unica forma de que cargue]

pero si lo agrego de esta manera nunca llega a carga
[image: aqui esta la manera en la que creo que deberia cargalo pero nunca carga y es la]

no se si tiene que ver que proj src se cargue fuera de la caperta proj pero el alchivo en el que agrego #include "EncryptionUtils.h" ya esta cargado en el proj estoy cometiendo algun ver
[image: no se si tiene que ver que proj src se cargue fuera de la caperta proj pero el alchivo en el que agrego #include "EncryptionUtils.h" ya esta cargado en el proj estoy cometiendo algun ero]

Comment: Hola Techi, bienvenido, la pregunta/respuesta debe ser autocontenida, esto es que no dependa de imágenes o enlaces, te sugiero que la edites, y la adaptes a los requerimientos del sitio, para que no sea cerrada, y evitar recibir votos negativos, 
mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.